# Java spring boot custom property type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, configuration

Я использую Java + Spring Boot, возникла необходимость добавить в файл `application.properties` поле - экземпляр какого-то своего типа (не String, не Integer, не...)
Например как-то так:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
public class MySuperCustomProperties {
    private SomeClass someProperty;

    // get set...
}
```

(Где `SomeClass` это какой-то собственный тип данных.)

Можно ли так сделать и если да, то как? (Нет ли такого интерфейса (например) реализовав который Spring сможет сам кастить строку в SomeClass)

Comment: `application.properties` - это файл настроек. Зачем туда добавлять экземпляр своего типа??? Это, конечно, загадка...

Comment: @notaProgrammer Ну например `server.port` это Integer, а мне нужен (my.custom.property) не встроенного типа, а своего

Comment: `.properties` файл это набор строковых пар ключ/значение. Поэтому `server.port` это строка, которая, разумеется может быть преобразована в Integer.

Comment: @notaProgrammer В этом и вопрос можно ли научить Spring кастить строку в SomeClass (чтобы не писать `new String(field)`)

Comment: Судя из Вашего вопроса, я так понимаю что Вы не совсем понимаете, что такое **Spring Container** и **Bean**'s, или как это работает. Рекомендую посмотреть эти [видеоуроки](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GB8k2-Egfv0&list=PLC97BDEFDCDD169D7).

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете для этого случая использовать @Bean.

application.properties:

```
springboot.field=field
```

MySuperCustomProperties.class:

```
@Configuration
public class MySuperCustomProperties {

    @Bean
    public SomeClass someProperty( @Value("${springboot.field}") String field ) {
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
        someClass.setField(field);
        return someClass;
    }

}
```

SomeClass.class:

```
public class SomeClass {

    private String field;

    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

}
```

Application.class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private SomeClass someClass;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(someClass.getField());
    }

}
```

Comment: SomeClass хранит в себе какие-то данные, и ведь в этом случае нельзя будет изменить их из `application.properties`

Comment: А уже те определенные данные вы можете записать в application.properties и через @Value их достать и через сеттер или конструктор записать в SomeClass

Comment: Прим сменил опираясь на ваши комментарии

Comment: Это я понял, но нельзя ли сделать так чтобы SomeClass парсил строку параметра (как например дата в виде строки это 01-01-2018, а не 3 параметра (день месяц год))?

Comment: @ScreamT5 а еще лучше создать свой файл `my.properties` и от туда доставать значения.

Comment: Вы можете внутри SomeClass прописать метод, который будет кастить это поле, а так что бы прям кастить целый класс, к сожалению не знаю.

Comment: @notaProgrammer Это понятно просто чтобы не усложнять вопрос я не стал об этом писать